# Problem with calculating how many times some date has passed midnight

Tags: python

I would like to ask for a help. I am a beginner when it comes to Python. I try to write a function, that sums up together two "times"  and returns new_time and also how many times new_time passed midnight of "start_time"(for example 23:00 and 03:00, new_date is 02:00, and 1 day has passed )

Thank you really much in advance

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def add_time(start_time: str, time_to_add: str):
    start_time_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M")
    add_time_time = datetime.strptime(time_to_add, "%H:%M")
    new_time = start_time_time + timedelta(minutes=add_time_time.minute, hours=add_time_time.hour)

    return f"New time is {new_time.strftime('%H:%M')}, XXX days after"

print(add_time("23:20", "19:20"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the dates for start_time_time and new_time. The number of days elapsed will be the difference (in days) between these dates.

I believe there are several ways to extract just the date from a "datetime", but I have just replaced the hours and minutes to zero.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def add_time(start_time: str, time_to_add: str):
    start_time_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, "%H:%M")
    start_date = start_time_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0)
    #print(start_date)
    add_time_time = datetime.strptime(time_to_add, "%H:%M")
    new_time = start_time_time + timedelta(minutes=add_time_time.minute, hours=add_time_time.hour)
    new_date = new_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0)
    #print(new_date)
    
    days_elapsed = (new_date - start_date).days
    
    return f"New time is {new_time.strftime('%H:%M')}, {days_elapsed} days after"

print(add_time("23:20", "19:20"))
```

The following code snippets demonstrates how to calculate the number of days after. You can uncomment the print statements to see what these dates actually represent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really clever solution for that problem :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I done mine in such as way that it should allow you to add example of 100hours, etc. Hope this helps.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Function that adds time HH:mm to a datetime object, adds set Hours and Minutes to start time and returns total days, hours, minutes and seconds passed
def add_time(start_time, time_to_add):
    # Add time to start time
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
    # Strip hours, minutes and convert to ms
    time_to_add = time_to_add.split(':')
    time_to_add = timedelta(hours=int(time_to_add[0]), minutes=int(time_to_add[1]))
    finish_time = start_time + time_to_add

    # Calculate total days, hours, minutes and seconds passed
    total_days = finish_time.day - start_time.day
    total_hours = finish_time.hour - start_time.hour
    total_minutes = finish_time.minute - start_time.minute
    total_seconds = finish_time.second - start_time.second

    # Return total days, hours, minutes and seconds passed
    return total_days, total_hours, total_minutes, total_seconds

# today + 23 hours + 20 minutes
days, hours, minutes, seconds = add_time("13:13", "25:00")

print(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this also helped me as mine solution didnt accept time, that exceeds 24h :)